# xamarin.forms binding from xaml to property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am a total newbie with bindings in xaml and I really don't get it sometimes.

I have this in my xaml:

```xml
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" />
```

The binding "IsLoading". Where do I declare/set this property?!

My .cs looks like this:

```cs
....
    public bool IsLoading;

    public CardsListXaml ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        IsLoading = true;
 ....
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bindings are typically resolved from the `BindingContext` property (in other implementations, this property is called `DataContext`). This is `null` by default (at least in other implementations of XAML), thus your view is unable to find the specified properties.

In your case, you must set the `BindingContext` property to `this`:

```
public CardsListXaml()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
    IsLoading = true;
}
```

However, this alone will not suffice. Your current solution does not implement a mechanism to notify the view of any property changes, so your view would have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Instead, I suggest you implement the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) pattern, which not only fits beautifully with data binding, but will result in a more maintainable and testable code base:

```
public class CardsListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isLoading;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isLoading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        }
    }

    public CardsListViewModel()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
    }

    //the view will register to this event when the DataContext is set
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your code-behind's constructor:

```
public CardsListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new CardsListViewModel();
}
```

Just to clarify, `DataContext` cascades down the visual tree, thus the `ActivityIndicator` control will be able to read to properties specified in the bindings.

Edit: Xamarin.Forms (and Silverlight/WPF etc... sorry, it's been a while!) also provides a [SetBinding](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/) method (see the *Data Binding* section).

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms` `BindableObject`s do not have `DataContext` properties, but a `BindingContext`