# Xamarin.Forms. Custom Property Binding issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I created custom controls in Xamarin. One of it is ValidatedEntryCell:

```
 public class ValidatedEntryCell: EntryCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowBorderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ShowBorder), typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatedEntryCell), false);
    public bool ShowBorder
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowBorderProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ShowBorderProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change that ShowBorder property in case if Text is empty. I tried several cases how to invoke  that property:

- Invoking that property straight forward in xaml. Smth like: `renderers:ValidatedPicker x:Name="Gender"  Title="Gender" ShowBorder="True"`
  That case works fine.
- `<renderers:ValidatedEntryCell ShowBorder="{Binding FirstNameIsNotValid}" x:Name="FirstName"`... (I setup `FirstNameIsNotValid = true` in codebehind)
- I used converters `<renderers:ValidatedEntryCell x:Name="LastName" ShowBorder="{Binding Source={x:Reference LastName},   Converter={StaticResource EmptyTextToBoolConverter}, Path=Text.Length}"` that always return `true`

Tried to use style triggers for property.
Unfortunately anything helps here. Will be glad for any advice

Edit: partially helps that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912960/xamarin-forms-binding-from-xaml-to-property?rq=1). For now I can setup property in constructor in codebehind and changes made will be visible.

Comment: So the 2 last cases aren't working or what's the problem? It's not really clear.

Comment: Sorry, I am bad in explanation. Yes, you are right. 2 last cases aren't working.